# In regards to GS1 barcode - what size DB field are used?

Tags: database-design, schema

In regards to GS1 barcode - what size DB field is used or is the entire GS1 typically not stored in database, but rather processed in the application layer and stored in the database as a collection of the component parts?

The length of the GS1 in its entirety is the subject of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16091593/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-gs1-code)

Comment: Are you planning on storing the ASCII characters or the image itself?  If ASCII characters, then you could use a `varchar(x)` field, where 'x' is the maximum length you need, or possibly a `varbinary(x)` field.

Comment: Planning on storing the ASCII characters unless someone with experience recommends parsing and storing.  Trying to find x.

Comment: That document you reference at GS1.org says `The maximum number of data characters in a single symbol is 48.` on page 253 under `GS1 - 128 Bar Code size characteristics:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the maximum number of characters in a single symbol is 48 and the Technical Spec for aggregators (http://www.gs1.org/sites/default/files/docs/gs1-source/TSD_v1_1_Technical_Implementation_Guide_for_Aggregators.pdf) indicates the file can come in as UTF-8. UTF-16, or UTF-32, the safest bet would be

```
nvarchar(48)
```